# android how to auto shrink imageview according to the screen size in tablayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I set 4 table rows weight to be 1. it works very well in different screen sizes. It will auto shrink and display all the images and fit the screen.

**But when i place it inside the Tablayout fragment, the content doesn't show all; as you can see from the screenshot.** Anyone know wads the problem ? Thx.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.template_tab.frag_two"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img0"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_4"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img5"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_5"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img6"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_6"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img7"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_7"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img8"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_8"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img9"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_9"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img10"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_10"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img11"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_11"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/display_text"
        android:text="1908, 1920, 1932, 1944, 1956, 1968, 1980, 1992, 2004, 2016, 2028, 2040, 2052, 2064"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout file

Comment: just added. plz have a look

Comment: `layout_weight="1"` on `TableRow` wouldn't have any affect until you also set it's `layout_height` to `0dp` so that it's equally divides height

Comment: @Sharj I changed to 0dp for height , it still doesn't work. the effect is same..

Comment: any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need TableRow for your case, also TableRow are supposed to be used inside TableLayout.

Set parent view to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.template_tab.frag_two"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img0"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_4"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img5"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_5"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img6"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_6"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img7"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_7"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img8"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_8"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img9"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_9"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img10"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_10"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="9dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img11"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_11"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/display_text"
        android:text="1908, 1920, 1932, 1944, 1956, 1968, 1980, 1992, 2004, 2016, 2028, 2040, 2052, 2064"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thx for ur effort. but it still doesn't work. the result is the same :(

Comment: any other solution ?

Comment: I tested it, it works correct. If your layout is inside a fragment then make sure height isn't wrap_content

Comment: it works well in normal layout. when i put it inside a  tablayout. it wont work

Comment: Post your complete layout of TabLayout

Comment: nvm, i already give up on this. i trying something else. thx for ur suggestion anyway.